# php date.timezone not working correctly for command line script only

Tags: php

I have this entry in my php.ini file:

```
date.timezone = 'Europe/London';
```

But every time i use the DateTime() in a command line script i still get the following error:

```
Exception: DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. 

You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. 

We selected 'Europe/London' for 'BST/1.0/DST' instead
```

I therefore have to do the following in any scripts to get this to work:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

What else can be causing this error?

**UPDATE**

I used the following in both command line and web browser:

```
<?php

var_dump(ini_get('date.timezone'));
exit;
```

In command line i get:

```
string(0) ""
```

In web browser i get:

```
string(13) "Europe/London"
```

Comment: Did you restart your server after changing the php.ini file?

Comment: Yes it has been restarted but the value has been set for a while anyway and the server has been restarted many times in between.  It is only now when i am writing a command line script that the Exception is occurring

Comment: Could you try echo ini_get('date.timezone'); and see what is actually set?

Comment: @user1572427 Did you verify that the CLI uses the same php.ini as the web server? Compare the ini file path shown by `php -i` at the command line with that shown by `phpinfo()` on the web server. I think it's likely you'll find they use different files.

Comment: edit the `php.ini` file you find by invoking `php -i`

Comment: I have experienced same error days ago.i fixed it by writing `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` **config.php** ( which is always included on all pages )

Comment: @DaveRandom Genius!  Thats it.  Can you put in an answer and ill accept.  Amazing!! Do you know if there is a way to pick up the timezone in php automatically from system if its not set in php.ini.  In order to make the code portable?

Comment: In addition to KingKrunch's answer, why don't you just create the time zone at the point of creating the DateTime object - `$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));` and you can stop worrying about editing the correct php.ini file.

Comment: @user1572427 Sort of the whole point of the warning is that it is *not safe* to rely on the system's timezone config (I'm not sure exactly why the PHP dev team feel this way, but apparently they do) - so the short answer to that is "No". Like N.B. suggests though, explicitly passing a `DateTimeZone` object to the `DateTime` constructor would be the way to handle that. You might as well accept KingCrunch's answer - it is after all the correct answer, and I'm not that rep hungry :-P

Comment: @DaveRandom Most server were usually installed with the default configuration, thus the timezones settings doesn't reflect the "real" location, where the server is. Additional the location of the server is often not the one, where the page is "virtually" located: I can create a page for german customers and let it host in Amazons EC2 in Ireland. This said: It's just not safe, to _rely_ on it ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch I get where you are coming from but I look at it in a slightly different way: Since PHP is server-side, the only time that is significant to PHP itself is the that of the server. When you start dealing with clients who may be in a different timezone to that of the server, it is the programmers responsibility to find out from the client where they are and adjust time calculations appropriately. Thus PHP should simply accept the timezone the server thinks it's in, and any adjustments to the contrary should be the responsibility of the programmer.

Comment: @KingCrunch I certainly don't think an exception (which halts execution and actually breaks the application) is an appropriate response to something that the developer has to deal with anyway for cross timezone applications, and anything targeted at a single timezone doesn't need to care about.

Comment: @DaveRandom You are right with the `Exception`... `date()` triggers a warning (as far as I remember? Don't know anymore :X), what is/would be much ... cooler. Regarding the different timezone-stuff: Especially when you are dealing with a cloud-based application your "server" is not in a single timezone anymore. However, I don't disagree with you. I'd just explained the thing why "don't trust the servers timezone" triggers a warning (or a completely oversized `Exception` with `DateTime` .... This message is much older then the buzzword "cloud computing" :D

Comment: @DaveRandom What I want to say: For PHP it's not important which timezone you set (you could always set the timezone to UTC (I do so)), but it wants you to set a timezone at all, because: Don't rely on the server ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch I love it when people say the want to move to "the cloud" - it gives me images of people sitting at desks in the classic TV representation of heaven, with all associated unicorns, cherubs with harps etc etc. I wonder which timezone God uses? Would an omnipresent entity be subject to timezones? These are questions that only God himself could answer. Or maybe Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

CLI and webserver (and cgi and fpm) use different `php.ini`-files. Because you say you see the right value in you browser I guess you edited the wrong one. On cli type

```
php --ini
```

To find out, which is the one you must edit. It's the one in the second line, for example

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

Some servers(Like media temple) do the configurations for the particular domains.So the server will access the common php.ini file which is under the /etc/php.ini but the browser access the domain's php.ini file.It may occurs the problem

Comment: It's about CLI, what is domain indepentent.