# Timezone getting ignored on the command line

Tags: php

The output of the following is two identiacal lines of UTC

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$datetime = new DateTime();
echo "\n" . $datetime->format('U');
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo "\n" . $datetime->format('U');
```

They should obviously be different, and neither should be UTC!

As well as setting the timezone in the code, its set in php.ini as

```
date.timezone = 'Europe/London'
```

PHP version is PHP 5.6.30, and all appears to be working when you use the web-browser, running on OS X.

Comment: remember PHP CLI has it's own ini file, double check settings there too.

Comment: Also, that's epoch time, seconds since January 1st 1970 UTC. That'll never change. Did you try another format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php date.timezone not working correctly for command line script only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108207/php-date-timezone-not-working-correctly-for-command-line-script-only)

Comment: @delboy1978uk - thanks, I had double checked that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They should obviously be different, and neither should be UTC!

Completely wrong. Twice.

The `U` format specifier of [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) prints the date as a timestamp. As the documentation explains in the ["Description"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) column, its meaning is *"Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)"*

You don't change the date or time stored in the `$datetime` object between the two calls to `DateTime::format()`, it is still the same date. The number of second passes since the Unix Epoch didn't change. There is no reason for the second call to `DateTime::format()` to print a different value.

Changing the timezone doesn't affect the date. It affects only how the date is represented using date & time components (years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, timezone).

A timestamp is an absolute representation of a date. It represents the number of seconds that passed since a fixed moment in the past. It doesn't depend on timezones.

Change the formatting to:

```
echo($datetime->format('U: Y-m-d H:i:s e')."\n");
```

and see for yourself:

```
1504791287: 2017-09-07 14:34:47 Europe/London
1504791287: 2017-09-08 02:19:47 Pacific/Chatham
```

Comment: ... feeling rather stupid... was staring at it for ages... thought I'd been through the docs... all sorted, bless you.

Comment: Changing timezone can affect date if the timezone difference crosses over midnight.

Comment: The timezone is a component of the date representation. It does not affect the date itself. In this very moment, it is Tuesday, 23:58 for me but it is already Wednesday for a lot of people that live on other timezones. But the moment in time is still the same. It is "now". Only the way how we express "now" using the date and time components differs. A Unix timestamp stores the number of seconds (the time) passed since Jan 1, 1970 0:00:00 UTC and this is the same for all of us.